# Resize issue of WordArt in Word 2016 (MS Office Professional Plus 2016)?

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting, microsoft-word-2016, typography, graphics-editing

I cannot resize the text in Word Art visually (i.e., by the GUI) in Word 2016. 
When I resize the text Word Art by click and dragging the box corner, it only increases the outer box size and not text size. Please compare there before and after pictures:
[image: In this pic I am starting to resize] 
[image: In this pic 2, After resizing it does not increase the text size only increase the outer box]
<sup>[Click to see larger images.]</sup>

But when I open a file that was made on Word 2007, it works the way I want. 
Compare:
[image: Word 2007 Word Art in 2016] 
[image: Watch it, I can resize it by dragging it like Photoshop resize]

How can I do that in Word 2016?

Answer (score 0):

It is the default behavior in Word 2016.
Resizing a WordArt object in the Word 2007 method only resizes the box the WordArt is in. The actual WordArt text behaves just like any other text in Word.

If you want to resize it simply select the text you want to resize and change the font size on the **Home** tab of the ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

I learned from another forum that if you highlight the WordArt, click on Drawing Tools then Format, you will see a link for Text Effects.  Highlight Transform (mine is at the bottom of the list) and then use the Warp effect.  The WordArt will now change with the size of the box.

I'm still looking for a way to make this behavior the default behavior but this is a good workaround for now.

Answer (score 0):

**How to resize WordArt in Microsoft Word 2022**

Here is the fix to resize the actual WordArt in a .docx format

1. After creating your WordArt, go to **Shape Format** *tab*
2. Look for **WordArt Styles**
3. Select **Text Effects**, located on the bottom right
4. Select **Transform**
5. Select **Warp** and click **Square** (Hover mouse above the first option, third row)

**Congratulations** you can now format your WordArt just like before